# Custom timeline tick with d3 and dc.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I have next chart:

```
scrollChart
   ...
   .x(d3.time.scale().domain([startDate, endDate]))
   .round(d3.time.minutes)
   .alwaysUseRounding(true)
   .xUnits(d3.time.minutes);
```

How can I change my `.xUnits` and `.round` to use each 5/10/15 minutes as an time interval?

*Update:*

Gordon's answer helped, but I have new problem after zooming.

This is 5 mins interval:
[image]

And after my zooming I have bad chart :( How can I 'reGroup' all to 1 min interval after filtering? Is it real?

[image]

Comment: [chart.round()](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.coordinateGridMixin.html#round__anchor) only affects the brush rounding. You probably want to aggregate by the time interval you're interested in. [Here is an example of switching between different time intervals.](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/switching-time-intervals.html)

Comment: @Gordon You are right, but I need custom timeline with my intervals, not `month`, `day`, `hour`

Comment: Gotcha, maybe try this thread? https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/dc-js-user-group/q_dO0pRf3vA

Comment: @Gordon Thank you, it's helped. Maybe write a little bit more info in the answer for other people.
Also I have one more problem now, can you help me, please? I updated my post.

Comment: Yes, that's a [known issue in dc.js](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/949). Basically it filters the points to those within the domain, when it needs to keep one more point off the edge. Although I have a comprehensive fix in a branch, it needs more work, so I will try to push a workaround under a flag right now. It's been bothering me for a long time (obviously).

Comment: Use the new flag [`chart.evadeDomainFilter(true)`](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.stackMixin.html#evadeDomainFilter__anchor) to work around this bug in dc.js. It's available in 2.0.4 and 2.1.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/676195/gordon) for help. 
I used `d3.js version 3` and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/dc-js-user-group/q_dO0pRf3vA) topic.
Firstly you need to copy `d3_time_interval` function, because it's not exposed.

Next I created function and use it in grouping.

```
const n_minutes_interval = (nMins) => {
    let denom = 6e4*nMins;
    return d3_time_interval(
         date => new d3_date(Math.floor(date / denom) * denom,
        (date, offset) => date.setTime(date.getTime() + Math.floor(offset) * denom, 
        date => date.getMinutes());
}

let myTimeInterval = n_minutes_interval(5);
let myGroup = dim.group(d => myTimeInterval(d)).someReduceFunction();
```