# dc.js xUnits custom time width

Tags: time, width, dc.js

I'm using dc.js and d3.js to create a chart.
Does anyone know how (and if its possible) to make the xUnits instead of minutes or hours a custom time value, like 20 minutes. I've tried using a function and googling but found nothing/ nothing came to mind.
Here is my fiddle of me experimenting.

https://jsfiddle.net/qjwwykju/

code dump because stack overflow wants me to:

```
var composite = dc.compositeChart("#test_composed");

var exp1 = [{
      start: '2017-12-16T00:00:00.000Z',
      count: 2
    },
    {
      start: '2017-12-16T00:20:00.000Z',
      count: 2
    },
    {
      start: '2017-12-16T00:40:00.000Z',
      count: 1.5
    },
    {
      start: '2017-12-16T00:60:00.000Z',
      count: 2.5
    }
  ],
  exp2 = [{
      start: '2017-12-16T22:00:00.000Z',
      count: 0.2
    },
    {
      start: '2017-12-16T11:50:00.000Z',
      count: 0.5
    },
    {
      start: '2017-12-16T16:00:00.000Z',
      count: 0.2
    },
    {
      start: '2017-12-16T19:00:00.000Z',
      count: 0.1
    }
  ],
  exp3 = [];

var ndx = crossfilter();

ndx.add(exp1.map(function(d) {
  return {
    x: +new Date(d.start),
    y3: 0,
    y2: 0,
    y1: d.count
  };
}));

ndx.add(exp2.map(function(d) {
  return {
    x: +new Date(d.start),
    y3: 0,
    y1: 0,
    y2: d.count
  };
}));

ndx.add(exp3.map(function(d) {
  return {
    x: +new Date(d.time),
    y1: 0,
    y2: 0,
    y3: d.complexity
  };
}));

var dim = ndx.dimension(dc.pluck('x')),
  grp1 = dim.group().reduceSum(dc.pluck('y1')),
  grp2 = dim.group().reduceSum(dc.pluck('y2')),
  grp3 = dim.group().reduceSum(dc.pluck('y3'));

composite
  .width(768)
  .height(480)
  .x(d3.time.scale().domain([new Date('2017-12-16T00:00:00.000Z'), new Date('2017-12-16T01:00:00.000Z')]))
  .legend(dc.legend().x(50).y(20).itemHeight(13).gap(5))
  .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
  .xUnits(d3.time.minutes)
  .renderVerticalGridLines(true)
  .compose([
    dc.barChart(composite)
    .dimension(dim)
    .group(grp1, "Active")
    .stack(grp2, "Initiated"),
    dc.lineChart(composite)
    .dimension(dim)
    .colors('#DE50E2')
    .group(grp3, "Complexity")
    .dashStyle([10, 2])
  ])
  .brushOn(true)
  .render();
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Where do find that SO wants you "code dump"?

Comment: ? I just wanted to post a jsfiddle but it says after a jsfiddle link I also need to post code, so I did. (sorry if I misunderstood the question)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom timeline tick with d3 and dc.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44655932/custom-timeline-tick-with-d3-and-dc-js)

Comment: I think I found the previous discussions you're looking for. Lmk if you need more help.

Comment: Yes it was, thanks alot, worked perfectly (even if it is a little dirty copy pasting the whole function) :)

Comment: It looks like [`d3.timeInterval` in d3 version 4](https://github.com/d3/d3-time/blob/master/README.md#timeInterval) supports custom time intervals directly. Someday [I hope to upgrade dc.js to d3v4](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1173) but it's a pretty big effort and I haven't found time yet. It is possible to use both versions of the library together but I can't say that's less icky than copy-pasting a function.